# Connect Micron SDRAM to STM32H7 FMC; what should I do with the DQM pin?

Tags: stm32, embedded, ram, sdram

I plan to connect SDRAM from the MICRON MT48LC series ([datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/671/256Mb_sdr-1282350.pdf)). The pin connection diagram is generated  automatically by STM32CubeMX (STM32H743). The setting is an 8-bit data bus, a 13-bit address, 4 banks, and clock and chip enable (SDCKE0 + SDNE0).

However, I found that there is no pin to connect to the Micron DQM pin. I saw some suggestions that if there is no use for DQM pin, it should connected to GND ([waclawek.jan answer](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkWw2SAF/stm32-with-sdram-how-to-connect-unused-dqms)), and also Micron suggests to leave it NC (float) ([the section "Unused DQ Pin"](https://www.micron.com/support/%7E/media/f9b2fb1d2b8c4efc8078247232e25b56.ashx)).

I dug into the truth table of the Command and DQ pins. this is the table:

[image]

The DQM signal is used for READ and WRITE operations and also "Write enable/output enable" and "Write inhibit/output High-Z". It seems that connecting DQM to GND for logic "L" is better than letting it float. This is the thing that is very unclear. How could I connect an STM32 with the Micron SDRAM DQM pin?

Comment: It is an input so yes, you should not let it float.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at section 21.9.2 of [the STM32H743 manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00314099.pdf) (shown below), you can see that the DRAM controller does have the ability to drive the DQM pins.  Perhaps it is the auto generate that is not working.  For an 8 bit interface, DQM on the SDRAM would likely connect to NBL0.

[image: Section 21.9.2]

The [STM32H743 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32h743bi.pdf) shows that NBL0 is connected for all packages:

[image]

Comment: NBL0 is available when I use the 16-bit data bus. However, this pin is not available in 8-bit data bus in STM32CubeMX